# Can't seem to access model properties on my cshtml file

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

So, I am working on a project that someone else before me created, and I am pretty new to MVC / asp.net:

so a little overview:
A user can submit a form.  After the form is created; a user can submit messages and some other entity can accept or close these forms.
The request: get rid of the ability to add more chat after a form is closed.

The form looks like this:
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqUw7.png

There is a method to add the message and it's an Ajax call,
the model is used in other parts of the code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    if ('@Model.RequestID' != '' .......
```

however, if I try to reference the model in other parts of the code or in the javascript console when attempting to create a conditional around that ajax call...  It seems all my attempts are undefined.

How can I access those property members inside of the model//properties of the form partial that I have rendered in that screenshot?

If this is not enough, I would be glad to expand on my question.

EDITS:

I am still confused:
At the top of the document,
the model is declared:

@model blahblahblahViewModel.

How can I access this model?

Whenever I try to do anything i get something likeeee:

VM282:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Model is not defined
    at :1:1

Im trying to access this inside of a function:
so like...

PS: PSUEDOCODE

```
function submitUserMessage() {

    var message = $('#btn-input').val();
    var id = $('#requestId').val();
    var user = $('#contactUser').val();
    var status = Model.GetStatus;

IF status = 'certain status'
Ajax call.
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the model, you need to unquote '@Modal.RequestId'.
    `if (@Model.RequestID != '')` or `if(isNullOrEmpty(@Model.RequestID))`

The reason you are not able to access the @Model in JavaScript console is because this is C# code. As you can see from the file's name, "cshtml", this is not a normal html file. 
The ASP.NET Engine renders this 'cshtml' file in the server-side, before returning a html file as the HTTPResponse back to the client's browser.

Another thing you might want to take note is, as of jQuery 3.0, `$(document).ready(func).` is considered deprecated. A better way to write it is: `$(function(){ }).` which really much concise.

Comment: I am still confused:
At the top of the document,
the model is declared: 

@model blahblahblahViewModel.

How can I access this model?

Whenever I try to do anything i get something likeeee:

VM282:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Model is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Im trying to access this inside of a function:
so like...
`
 function submitUserMessage() {
     
        var message = $('#btn-input').val();
        var id = $('#requestId').val();
        var user = $('#contactUser').val();
        var status = Model.GetStatus;

IF status = 'certain status'
Ajax call.`

Comment: I'll post this in my original question so I can format it.

Comment: Perhaps you want to post your full Model and View code here? Oh, just in case you are new to programming, pseudocode won't run and will cause errors, do remember to comment them out!

Comment: I typed it up as psuedo code to not reveal too much information about the company that I am working at... hmm... 
I'm trying to think what I can share..

Comment: Wish we could message users on here haha.

Comment: I think "not defined" errors are caused by improper imports or declarations/calls that are out of scope. Since your error appears to be caught at the first line of code, it doesn't make sense to me. It could be your project hasn't been built properly. Have you tried: Cleaning your solution > Rebuild solution > Build Solution?

If this doesn't work, then I really don't know how else to help you... But you might want to try to replicate this problem is a smaller project and post the source code along with the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that would be the right way to go...  Haha.
I will attempt to replicate in a smaller project.